# How to use uri with database name in php mongodb library

Tags: php, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I've probably spent more time than I should in this.
I'm using heroku to deploy php & mongodb application.

Heroku mLab gives env variable MONGODB_URI accessible in php through getenv('MONGODB_URI') which contains standard MongoDBURI like:

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@dsxxxxxx.mlab.com:31899/heroku_lxxxxxx
```

which already contains existing database name, but php mongodb library tutorial suggests connect string without it:

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->demo->beers;
```

So the question is can I use default heroku's MONGODB_URI string somehow, or I have to parse_uri it and then feed to php separately.

Comment: Have you tried creating client with mlab connect string ? http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.construct.php. Btw you should use the latest php driver. http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php

Comment: Yes, I've created client, but then I still need to parse uri to extract dbname and select it manualy regarding it was already passed to client constructor.

Comment: That is authentication db as part of URI. You just connect to database holding your collections. Something like `$db = $client->selectDB("dbname"); $collection = $db->collectionname`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand what the string 'mongodb://localhost:27017' is. It basically tells the drivers to connect to mongodb server running on localhost on port 27017 without authentication. Thats fairly simple. Now heroku manages your database which is hosted on separate server and needs authorication, so the new code should be

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@dsxxxxxx.mlab.com:31899/heroku_lxxxxxx");
```

Now the above being said is again wrong, because the username and password or even the host might change in future and you don't want to make changes in the codebase just because of that. Thats why environment variables comes to the rescue. use php `getenv` method to get the string from heroku instance. I don't know the exact name of variable but you can get that from docs and finally pass that string when you initialize the mongodb drivers.

### Edit

Just noticed you mentioned `MONGODB_URI` in the question so the code would be

```
$mongoHost = getenv('MONGODB_URI');
$client = new MongoDB\Client($mongoHost);
```

Comment: Hi georoot! Yeah, I understand that and have similar code, but how can I access collection now? In php doc example they have line like $collection = $client->{$dbname}->{$collectionname}. If I passed dbname to Client constructor what should I do then?

Comment: Have a look at docs http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php . The $m in the docs is same as $client over here.

Comment: So I still need to parse uri first to separate dbname? I do understand that it's only a 1-2 lines of code, but it just feels wrong, as long as it wasn't necessary with old Mongo php extension.